# unique live valdation of multiple columns in array

Tags: php, laravel, validation, unique

For my little project I need to save multiple players in the database.
Everything is working fine so far but I have a big problem with my unique live validation that my rule is not working as soon as I comment it in.

First of all, I saved only one Player without an array in single variables and the rule worked perfectly. As soon as I used this code (you will see below), my rule is not working anymore but I have to save them in an array.  If I will set the variables on top it will work, but live validation is not working obviously.
Maybe someone has an idea how to fix it - would be very thankful!

Edit:I also tried something like this:

'allPlayers.*.lastname' => 'required|unique:players,lastname'

The import thing is, that one player has to be unique with the combination of firstname and lastname aswell as title(sex) and birthday

'''

```
public $players;        


public $player = [
    'title' => '',
    'firstname' => '',
    'lastname' => '',
    'birthday' => '',
    'department' => '',
];
public $allPlayers = [];


public function mount()
{
    $this->allPlayers[] =  $this->player;
}

protected function rules()
{
    return
        [
            'allPlayers.*.title'                         => 'required',
            'allPlayers.*.firstname'                     => 'required|string|max:40',
            'allPlayers.*.lastname'                      => ['required', Rule::unique('players')->where(function ($query) {$query->where('lastname', $this->lastname)
                                                                                                                                   ->where('firstname', $this->firstname)
                                                                                                                                   ->where('birthday', $this->birthday)
                                                                                                                                   ->where('title', $this->title); })],                                                                                                                     
            'allPlayers.*.birthday'                      => 'required|date',
            'allPlayers.*.department'                    => 'required',
        ];
}



public function updated($propertyName)
{
    $this->validateOnly($propertyName);   
}


public function store()
{

    $validatedData = $this->validate();
    dd($validatedData);
    Player::insert($validatedData['allPlayers']);



   
    session()->flash('message', 'Spieler erfolgreich angelegt');
}
```

'''

Comment: your validation is wrong as per your data type `$allPlayers = [['title' => '',], ['title' => '']]` this kind of data your need to make this validation work

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kamlesh but I did not get what you mean - I am sorry! Did you mean I have to put in every variable like you said in my 'public $allPlayers'?

Comment: as per your validation yes you need to push on that arry

Comment: I tried your idea but it does not work for me. I wrote my public $allPlayers like you said for every variable (title, firstname, lastname, birthday and department), got on my view page multiple rows but validation still not working. Maybe it is possible that you can show what you mean? Would really appreciate it!

Comment: i think your realtime validation only not works

Comment: Can I rewrite my unique rule maybe? Because if I will do my inserts I get the following message: Property [$lastname] not found on component: [players]

Comment: and thats the one of the big problems because my rule is not working inside the array